# Objective-C not recognizing .h?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, import

I have the following in a project named testApp: (testAppViewController is the valid name of my view controller in the project)

**PrevView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "testAppViewController.h"

@interface PrevView : UIView {
    testAppViewController *viewController;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) testAppViewController *viewController;

@end
```

When I build the project I'm getting the following error:

> `PrevView.h:13: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'testAppViewController'`

Am I missing something here? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does "testAppViewController.h" import "PrevView.h"?

If so, you may want to delcare a forward class reference:

```
@class testAppViewController;
```

that replaces the import you have, and move the import into the .m file.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when I see this type of error, it's a problem in the header file that you're trying to import. Check "testAppViewController.h"